# CLLocationManager sometimes provides wrong coordinates on iOS 13

Tags: cllocationmanager, ios13

Sometimes location manager gives GPS-point, which is located about hundreds meters, or several kilometers away from real device location. After it location manager continues provide us with wrong coordinates, which slowly became closer to real device location.

Such points have quite good accuracy about ~30 - ~65 meters, and some of them have speed > 0 m/s.

[image: wrong points path]

real path was:
[image: real path]

Authorization status is "Always allow"

location manager is adjustment:

```
CLLocationManager *manager = [CLLocationManager new];
manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
manager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = YES;
manager.distanceFilter = 50; // meters
manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
manager.delegate = self;
```

This problem is actual only for iOS 13. I made about 50 experiments, registering movement trajectories of ~5 km - ~150 km length. Same code works perfectly with iOS 12.

Comment: You might want your app to consider the [`horizontalAccuracy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423599-horizontalaccuracy) of the location updates before deciding to add them to the path.

Comment: @Rob these wrong points have good value of `horizontalAccuracy`